# A mod migrated my old question from RC to here --- where I have already asked a new better question

Tags: support

I have asked [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/120797/why-did-a-tradition-to-add-a-must-use-default-array-to-functions-was-created-and) on Retrocomputing SE; it got answers there, but was later closed and commenters suggested it would be a better fit for Computer Science SE.

Because my Retrocomputing question already got answers, I couldn't delete it before reposting a similar, better question, on Computer Science SE.

So, I went to Computer Science and posted a similar question there which is per my humble opinion [shorter, more focused, and better phrased](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/120796/why-in-general-must-function-declarations-be-followed-by-a-parameter-set).

But, after doing so, my old question from Retrocomputing SE was reopened and migrated to Computer Science SE; hence:

[Now, in CS SE, there is a "salad" of two similar questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/115711/johndoea?tab=questions) which per my humble opinion, needs to be merged somehow --- comments and answers from the old should be migrated to the new, I think.

### My question

I already contacted the mods of Computer Science explaining the problem and asking to merge the questions, but AFAIR, the flag was declined.

Will you, a mod, move all comments and answers from the old question into the [new one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/120796/why-in-general-must-function-declarations-be-followed-by-a-parameter-set)?

Comment: I agree that the questions are similar, and that answers should be in one place. I disagree, however, on which question should be kept. I think it is better to keep the old question and change the title (either the revised one from the other site or something similar to the new question would be fine), since it seems that one has many more substantial answers. Could you explain why you want to have a merge in the other direction? I've closed the new question as a duplicate of the old for now, so that at least new answers end up in one place. (also, closing can be changed, unlike merging)

Comment: Oh and while another moderator declined your flag, it seems it was declined because you did not actually ask what you wanted us to do (See also [your flag summary](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/115711) for the reply). In particular, we do not know any more about why this question was migrated than you do, you should ask that to whoever migrated the question.

Comment: Hello @Discretelizard ; I sadly disagree that only changing the title of the old question is good - I hold the opinion that the entire question should be changed (be 100% similar to the new one). The direction of merging doesn't matter to me as long as long as the new question is kept and all answers are on its very own place.

Comment: @Discretelizard I just saw that two hours later I did clarify what I asked (under all hardship and pressure of this issue) ; I kindly tell you, with humbleness, that I think something should have been done already; so, I myself cloned the new question and title in the "old" one but I think that the comments and answers should go there as well so we would have this in one place indeed.

Comment: Ok, I merged the questions. As for the edit, sure, the current wording is fine too.

Comment: Thank you dearly @Discretelizard, for this rewarding help in an approach I grasp as nice ; issue set for me.